# I thought she liked me?

Tags: logical-deduction

I'm a young programmer from NYC attending a conference in London. Last night I met a fellow developer in a bar she was young, beautiful and had the sexiest English accent!

As the evening drew to a close she pulled my hand close to her, pulled out a pen and wrote her phone number on it.

> 01861 919550

My heard skipped a beat, this vision of geeky beauty really did like me!

It's now the following morning, I've tried to call her but number isn't recognised. I'm devastated, please help me find my lost love before I have to go back to the US!

Suggested Edit:

After some help it's been suggested that

> 01861 919220

Actually works better, I've edited it into the question to help anyone wanting to solve it!

Comment: I hope that's not actually a real phone number... I'm gonna get some serious downvotes if it is!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to hear about your lost love. Have you tried

> Calling 05561 619810 - I think you may have read the number upside down!

Comment: Very very close... you've got the right idea - the clue is in the city (assuming I've worked it out correctly)

Comment: I did think that it didn't look like a valid phone number but worth a try. :) I can't think how London would make a difference though sadly I'll keep thinking though. :)

Comment: You are sooooo close... like 9 out of 11

Comment: In that case I am totally baffled. I could change the beginning to 020 to make it londony but I have no reason to do that. :( Or more likely I'd try to work out if it should start 07... since everybody gives out mobile numbers these days. Who gives out a land line? ;-)

Comment: My intention was the 5 and 2s swap (02 being London code) in the same way you've changed 6s and 9s because you've turned it over. I'd have done a mobile but 7s don't reverse!

Comment: A 5 to 2 would be a reflection if anything I'd have thought, not a rotation. I did think that when you said two wrong...

Comment: And reflection wouldn't work for any number with a 6 or a 9 in it, since that doesn't become a different valid number.

Comment: @Liath, you should change the last to 5's to 2's to make it better.

Comment: Probably my error - either way you spotted the flip first!

Comment: Next time just get her to program it straight into your phone and test it there and then. ;-)

Comment: Also as an afterthought I note that according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dialling_codes_in_the_United_Kingdom 022 is not a london number (and is not anything in fact).

Answer (score 2):

assuming she wrote it down upside down to yourself but the right way to her

01861 919550

022616 19810

OR

055616 19810

depending on whether an upside down 5 is a 2 or not

Comment: Personally I am not sure how an upside down five would be a 2. 2 has a closed bottom left and top right and when rotated still has a closed bottom left and top right. 5 has a closed bottom right and a closed top left. Likewise under rotation it will be the same. I'd be interested to see a picture of a 2 or 5 that would look like the other under rotation.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment on Chris's answer, the clue is in the city.

Have you tried calling

> +44 1861 919550 - if you're in NYC (maybe you flew back), you're ringing an American number, she's English

Comment: Sorry - not to do with international numbers, I've edited the question to clarify I'm still in the UK.